# QVector Deep Copy

Tags: qt, qt5, deep-copy, qvector

I'm trying to deep copy my variable:

```
QVector<PetTeam*> petTeam;
```

This PetTeam class also has another QVector containing pets and so on. I am looking to deep copy them all so I can use them for states in an minimax AI but so far I have been unable to deep copy it correctly.

If anyone could provide any insight on the correct way to deep copy in this situation it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy all `PetTeam` objects automatically, you need to declare your vector as `QVector<PetTeam> petTeam`. It requires `PetTeam` to have a constructor without parameters and a copy constructor. They are generated automatically but you should reimplement them if `PetTeam` contains any information that can't be copied trivially (e.g. file handlers, pointers to manually allocated memory, etc.)

Another option is to copy your objects manually, i.e. iterate over the list and create a new object for each old object using `new PetTeam(...)` and then put them in the new list.

Comment: I am looking to iterate over the list and create a new object for each old object but I can't seem to do it correctly. I cannot use an iterator because any iterator cannot be taken from a const variable.

So I'm stuck using size() which isn't that bad but then once I have to select the indices from the original I can't think of any other way but to use .at(i) which doesn't deep copy anything.